# Can XSS Be Used To Modify A Part Of My Website, One That Was Not Intended To Be Modified?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I am researching XSS, and all I can find so far is that javascript can be used
to 
1) inject malicious code into let's say a profile page. (A page that is intended to be modified). Or 
2) that HTML and javascript can be used to modify the properties of a client-side page as displayed in the browser, and 
3) that it can perhaps query information from the web server on the page's privilege level server-side.

Should I fear that an XSS vulnerability on my website can actually modify my website's pages server side? (Make some changes that everyone is affected by)

Comment: it could if the current context has rights to do.

Comment: Imagine this: A user successfully changes their profile name to `John <script>alert('hi');</script> Doe`. This is saved in your database. You then introduce a comment feature on your website where users names are displayed alongside comments they leave. Mr. Doe here then posts a comment on your page. Your page pulls his name and comment from your database and boom, an alert pop-up with the text "Hi" appears for every visitor who visits that page.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But is that only if the vulnerability is one that causes code to be executed by the web server?

Thanks James, that's what I've learned and summarized in point # 1.

Wish people would tell me why they -1 my questions. Don't know why, so I can't learn to not make the mistake next time.

Comment: People are giving you -ses because you didn't really read anything about XSS in the first place, and you just go straight to the question box, which is not CREATIVE, because there are allready lots of related questions

Comment: Uhm no Eda I DID read about XSS in the first place. Are you blind and not see the first few lines?

Must be ignorant people like you then. Thanks for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSS Can modify a part of your website, perhaps even one that was not intended to** if your website has input objects that get processed by the webserver.
If the input reader function of your web server has Full Access Rights, and the function is not "picky" therefore does not escape potential user written code, it may execute malicious code that causes it to make changes to the website and any connected resources server-side. (Because this execution happens server side, these changes will be viewed by all new visitors to your website.)

You can only inject malicious items through URL requests or input fields on a website.

Javascript injected on the client side can collect the values of JavaScript variables. It can also steal information such as cookies with login tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make differences between **Server-side language** (PHP for example) and **Client-side language**(HTML, CSS, Javascript). Attacker may have various attack choices, depending on vulnerability on your website. For example if you let users post comments and don't do ANYTHING with the text they type in, they COULD inject any HTML, CSS, or Javascript INTO your website, like if YOU did that. This could lead to data theft, and attacker would be able to retrieve data of ANYONE who visits a page injected by him (again depending on your site). They cannot use server side languages like PHP on your website.
TLDR; You make attackers ADMINS, and they can even redirect your users to their own page.

Comment: That was not long at all, I for one read entire posts instead of skim read like the ones who -1 me seem to do. :)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: BTW. Javascript is ALSO used for server side scripting. Your answer is a little off but I'll correct it for you.

Comment: So what answer do you expect? You didn't provide any sort of your code, so people could only answer broadly like I did. Please, edit your question or explain what exactly you need from us.

Comment: "Server-side language (PHP for example) and Client-side language(HTML, CSS, Javascript)."

javascript is both client and server side. I don't want people to be misinformed.

Also because you only gave the information I already said I had found in the question itself.